# How to flag certain rows of a table according to a value?

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb

I have a mongodb collection and I'm using node.js . I have a collection for "clothes" and I represent the data of it in this table :

```
 <h2>Clothes</h2>       
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>

        <th>price</th>
        <th> date </th>
        <th>Delete</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        <% for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){%>
        <% if(result[i].type == "price"){%>
        <tr>

            <td><%= result[i].price %></td>
            <td><%= result[i].date %></td>
            <td>
                <form action="/delete-price" method="POST">
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<%= result[i]._id %>">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete">
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <%}%>
        <%}%>

    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Date can be any day of the week . My question is , I want to make the user submit a certain budget through a form(which is easy)  , but I want at the same time to compare all the expenses of all the rows to it

The table is working and fully functional as well as the database.

An example:

```
    Ex: If the user enters budget of 200$ , I should go to all the rows in 

"Clothes" , check the prices, if the prices is greater than the budget, this 

row should be flagged .
```

How can I achieve this? I'm very new to this . I tried to do this in html and css but this is where my knowledge stops

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try something like this,

```
function flagClothes (clothes, userPrice){
 return clothes.map(function(price) {
   if(userPrice < price) return 'flagged' // I dont know exactly do you mean with flagged so i just return text, you can return anything.

 })
};
```

I hope it helps